# Python C-API and Numpy: core dump on import_array

Tags: python, numpy, coredump, python-c-api

```
//testNumpy.c
#include<Python.h>
#include<numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("import_array\n");fflush(stdout);
    import_array();
    printf("import_array done\n");fflush(stdout);
}

$ gcc -I/usr/include/python2.6 -lpython2.6 testNumpy.c&&./a.out
import_array
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong on such a simple program?  I'm tearing my hair out :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, you did not initialize Python properly. Call [Py_Initialize()](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html) before trying to initialize NumPy.